# surah 67 verse 4 - how does sight 'return' to you?

Tags: quran, tafseer, science

Sight does not travel away from a human and then come back, so how can it return?

What happens is that light hits you eye, it does not travel away from you and then come back to your eye.

Tafsirs seem to indicate that this is to be taken literal.

Comment: Not sure why you decided to delve into light and eyes. The verse just says turn your sight all you want to the sky, you'll only get tired and return your sight to yourself. You know light does not get tired right? But, you looking at the sky get tired and bring back your sight to the ground.

Comment: @TheZ barak allahu fik

Answer (score 0):

The ironies of literature and written jokes must be understood delicately.
God created the feet for man to walk, but the fact that some people like to walk on their hands does not create a hindrance for the creature!
To understand this verse correctly, one must act in the right way. And biasedly looking for error among the verses of the Qur'an is not the right way.

This verse (67:4) "Look again, once more. Your look will return to you humbled and weary."
This verse has beautiful and profound interpretations. God, who has done His work firmly and wisely, is not worried about the accuracy of others' opinions, but invites others to visit. It is also not enough to see and observe once to gain knowledge. Rather, one must look at the creation of the universe again and again in order to gain knowledge about it.
In another interpretation, it can be said that the meaning of "Look again"  is the same as thinking. Not eyes and sight and just seeing.